# How can I modify a migration in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm trying to modify a existing migration. Here is my current migration class:

```
class CreateLogForUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('log_for_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('table_name');
            $table->string('error_message');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('error_code');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('log_for_user');
    }
}
```

I've executed the `php artisan migrate` command once. Now I need to add `->nullable()` method to the `error_message` column. So I edited my migration, something like this:

```
.
.
    $table->string('error_message')->nullable();
.
.
```

But when I execute `php artisan migrate` again, it says:

> Nothing to migrate.

How can I apply the new version of the migration?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should create a new migration using command:

```
php artisan make:migration update_error_message_in_log_for_user_table
```

Then, in that created migration class, add this line, using the `change` method like this:

```
class UpdateLogForUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('log_for_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('error_message')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('log_for_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('error_message')->change();
        });
    }
}
```

To make these changes and run the migration, use the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

and to rollback the changes, use the command:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

You may rollback a limited number of migrations by providing the `step` option to the rollback command. For example, the following command will rollback the last five migrations:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=5
```

> See more about [Modifying columns with Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns)

Comment: Just one question, when exactly should I use `change()` method? If I want to add an index *(like `unique()`)* instead of `nullable()`, still do I need to use `change()` like this? `$table->string('error_message')->unique()->change();`

Comment: Yes, `change` method tells laravel to modify that particular query!

Comment: @stack - according to laravel perquisite install this package - `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Comment: And my last question, how can I get one step back? I mean, suppose I've created a new migration and added expected changes and executed `php artisan migrate`, I regret now,  how can I go back one step?

Answer (score 11):

If your app is not in production and you seed your data, the best you can do is to run:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

This command will drop all tables and recreate them. Then it will seed the data.

If you will create additional migrations for each change during development, you'll end up with hundreds of migrations classes.

Comment: In this case, current dataset will be removed, right?

Comment: Yes, data will be lost. But the right way is to seed the data during development, but not use the real data.

Comment: I see. Juse one thing, what `--seed` does exactly? I know what `migration:refresh` does, but I don't know what `--seed` does ..

Comment: It runs seeders, does the same as `php artisan db:seed` command. You can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding#running-seeders).

Comment: Honestly still *seeding* database is vague for me .. What exactly *"seed"* means in database? Does it fill the database by unreal data? Well where those data come from?

Comment: Yes, usually you're using fake data generated by model factories. But you can seed real data if you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`change`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns) method, it allows you to modify some existing column types to a new type or modify the column's attributes.

For example modify a column to be nullable:

```
Schema::table('log_for_user', function ($table) {
    $table->string('error_message')->nullable()->change();
});
```

But first of all you'll need the `doctrine/dbal` [package](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal)

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: Just one question, when exactly should I use `change()` method? If I want to add an index *(like `unique()`)* instead of `nullable()`, still do I need to use `change()` like this? `$table->string('error_message')->unique()->change();`

Comment: You don't need `change` method for `unique`. Just use it like this `$table->unique('error_message');` in a new migration file.

Comment: It is "composer require doctrine/dbal" (you are missing a letter)

Answer (score 4):

There is one more option. Roll back the migration, edit the file, and run it again.

This is a fairly common thing to do on a local development server while you're working out the bugs in a new piece of code. Using the method from the accepted answer, you might end up with 17 migrations for creating a single table!

```sh
php artisan migrate
# realize you've made an error
php artisan migrate:rollback
# edit your migration file
php artisan migrate
```

The number of steps back to take can be specified on the command line if needed.

```sh
# undo the last 3 migrations
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=3
```

Or you can specify a particular migration that needs undoing.

```sh
# undo one specific migration
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=./database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_users_table.php
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Run `php artisan migrate:refresh`. This will rollback all your
   migrations and migrate all your migrations. If you run this command,
   all the data inserted in your database will be lost.
2. Run `php artisan make:migration enter_your_migration_name_here`.
   Then insert this in your migration:

   `$table->string('error_message')->nullable()->change();`

   Then run `php artisan migrate` to make your table changes. (Take note that when you do this, you have require `composer require doctrine/dbal` in your composer)